# CSS repeat background-image but no-repeat for linear-gradient

Tags: css, background-image, overlay, repeat, linear-gradients

I have a cool noise overlay PNG that I'd like to use on my website.
However, the background image is a linear gradient. 
If I allow background-repeat, it overlays the PNG correctly, but if the page content is shorter than the screen size, it repeats the gradient as well, which looks horrible.

Is there a way I can use CSS to repeat the PNG overlay, but **not** the linear gradient?

```
BODY {
background-color:#dedede;
background-image: url(icons/noise_overlay.png)
                , linear-gradient(
                      #c0bbbb
                    , #efefef 25em
                    , #efefef calc(100% - 15em)
                    , #dedede
                  );
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Does `html, body {min-height: 100%}` help?

Comment: Not a bad idea, but the footer content and the bg-gradient need to line up with each other in this instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can comma separate the background properties for each background

```
BODY {
background-color:#dedede;
background-image: url(icons/noise_overlay.png)
                , linear-gradient(
                      #c0bbbb
                    , #efefef 25em
                    , #efefef calc(100% - 15em)
                    , #dedede
                  );
background-repeat:repeat, no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Works a charm! Thanks very much.